# Query latest date

Tags: sql

I have the below query:

```
SELECT 

 a.JobStatusID
,a.JobID    
,a.JobNavn
,b.AdjustmentDate
,b.ExpTypeDescr 
,b.Invoiced
,b.ActualPL 

from Job a
          INNER JOIN JobAdjustmentDetails b on b.JobId = a.jobid
          INNER JOIN SysJobtype c on c.JobTypeID = a.JobTypeID

WHERE a.JobID BETWEEN '700000' AND '799999' 

GROUP BY
   a.JobID,
ROLLUP (
     a.JobStatusID
,a.JobNavn
,b.AdjustmentDate
,b.ExpTypeDescr 
,b.Invoiced 
,b.ActualPL
)
```

That returns the data as below:

[image]

Can anyone advise the best way to only pull through the latest date for my column AdjustmentDate?

For example I would like an output as below:

[image]

**The full query will pull through multiple jobs with differing dates so I just want to be able to see the max date for each jobid.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't pretty and there are better ways, but I guess this should work and is understandable:

```
SELECT 

 a.JobStatusID
,a.JobID    
,a.JobNavn
,b.AdjustmentDate
,b.ExpTypeDescr 
,b.Invoiced
,b.ActualPL 

from Job a
          INNER JOIN JobAdjustmentDetails b on b.JobId = a.jobid
          INNER JOIN SysJobtype c on c.JobTypeID = a.JobTypeID

WHERE a.JobID BETWEEN '700000' AND '799999' 
and b.AdjustmentDate = (select max(b.AdjustmentDate)
from Job a
          INNER JOIN JobAdjustmentDetails b on b.JobId = a.jobid
          INNER JOIN SysJobtype c on c.JobTypeID = a.JobTypeID

WHERE a.JobID BETWEEN '700000' AND '799999' )

GROUP BY
   a.JobID,
ROLLUP (
     a.JobStatusID
,a.JobNavn
,b.AdjustmentDate
,b.ExpTypeDescr 
,b.Invoiced 
,b.ActualPL
)
```

It does the same query again but only picks the max date.

EDIT:

per Job ID i would make a CTE I guess. Can you check if this works?

```
/* Formatted on 3-3-2020 19:05:25 (QP5 v5.300) */
with cte as (SELECT MAX (b.AdjustmentDate) AdjustmentDate, a.JobID
                    FROM Job a
                         INNER JOIN JobAdjustmentDetails b ON b.JobId = a.jobid
                         INNER JOIN SysJobtype c ON c.JobTypeID = a.JobTypeID
                   WHERE a.JobID BETWEEN '700000' AND '799999'
                   group by a.JobID
                   )
  SELECT a.JobStatusID,
         a.JobID,
         a.JobNavn,
         b.AdjustmentDate,
         b.ExpTypeDescr,
         b.Invoiced,
         b.ActualPL
    FROM Job a
         INNER JOIN JobAdjustmentDetails b ON b.JobId = a.jobid
         INNER JOIN SysJobtype c ON c.JobTypeID = a.JobTypeID
         INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.JobID = a.JobID and b.AdjustmentDate = CTE.AdjustmentDate
   WHERE     a.JobID BETWEEN '700000' AND '799999'
GROUP BY a.JobID,
         ROLLUP (a.JobStatusID,
                 a.JobNavn,
                 b.AdjustmentDate,
                 b.ExpTypeDescr,
                 b.Invoiced,
                 b.ActualPL)
```

This gives the the below results.  The green highlighted rows are the correct info but I am receiving 2 additional rows per ExpTypeDescr?

[image: Results added by PipRon7]

Comment: Thanks for this.  That gives me what I want but only for the jobid that has the latest date... for example 704289 has the latest date of 29/02/2020 so it only shows that job... Is there a way i can get the max date for each jobid?

Comment: Updated my post. Don't know if that gives the results you want.

Comment: This is almost exactly what i want but the results are creating extra lines.  I see each line as i hope but then 2 additional random lines for each ExpTypeDescr?  I have added the results to your post

Comment: I think that could be the rollup, although im not sure why it is returning 3 rows. The CTE query should give you one row for your jobid, and we inner join on that. Can you tell me what you are rolling up for? I can't see it in your results. Could you run the query without the rollup?

Comment: But look at other columns like `Invoiced` or `ActualPL` - for one JobID and a specific date, the values may still differ. The duplicates could be removed with a `distinct` in the "main" query, but only if the values for these other columns are the same. As it is not the case, additional logic must be added for these.

Comment: Ronald - removing the roll up worked perfectly!  Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: great, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to use aggregate function MAX on date and group by necessary fields.

```
SELECT 

     a.JobStatusID
    ,a.JobID    
    ,a.JobNavn
    ,MAX(b.AdjustmentDate)
    ,b.ExpTypeDescr 
    ,b.Invoiced
    ,b.ActualPL 

FROM Job a
    INNER JOIN JobAdjustmentDetails b on b.JobId = a.jobid
    INNER JOIN SysJobtype c on c.JobTypeID = a.JobTypeID

WHERE a.JobID BETWEEN '700000' AND '799999' 

GROUP BY
    a.JobID
    ,a.JobStatusID,
    ,a.JobNavn
    ,b.ExpTypeDescr
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately i am still receiving the older dates as before.  I would like to only pull through the max date for each job if possible

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from tablename
WHERE AdjustmentDate=CURRENT_DATE() ;
```

Comment: Could you provide a context for your answer? this is a low quality one.

Answer (score -1):

Would be better if you compare it to the current date instead of using MAX as showing below:

```
a.JobStatusID
,a.JobID    
,a.JobNavn
,b.AdjustmentDate
,b.ExpTypeDescr 
,b.Invoiced
,b.ActualPL 

from Job a
          INNER JOIN JobAdjustmentDetails b on b.JobId = a.jobid
          INNER JOIN SysJobtype c on c.JobTypeID = a.JobTypeID

WHERE a.JobID BETWEEN '700000' AND '799999' AND b.AdjustmentDate=CURRENT_DATE()

GROUP BY
   a.JobID,
   a.JobStatusID,
   a.JobNavn,
   b.ExpTypeDescr
```